# Error: The process '/Users/runner/work/1/s/android/gradlew' failed with exit code 1

Tags: java, android, react-native

/Users/runner/work/1/s/android/app/src/main/java/com/bpapp/MainApplication.java:9: error: package io.github.elyx0.reactnativedocumentpicker does not exist
import io.github.elyx0.reactnativedocumentpicker.DocumentPickerPackage;
^
1 error

> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
> ReactNativeFirebase WARNING: NPM package '@react-native-firebase/analytics' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v12.4.0 but found v11.5.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.

Comment: Is this all? There's supposed to be some Gradle output before that? Can you check if you find the full build logs?

Comment: @JoachimSauerFAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log out

Comment: @Joachim
1 error

> Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
ReactNativeFirebase WARNING: NPM package '@react-native-firebase/analytics' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v12.4.0 but found v11.5.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Comment: @Joachim Sauer  /Users/runner/work/1/s/android/app/src/main/java/com/bpapp/MainApplication.java:9: error: package io.github.elyx0.reactnativedocumentpicker does not exist
import io.github.elyx0.reactnativedocumentpicker.DocumentPickerPackage;

Comment: @JoachimSauer   I m not able to post everything at single comment can you please check is this information fine

Comment: You're not supposed to cram all of that into comments. Edit your question with that information instead!

Comment: @JoachimSauer Sure please check now

Comment: So where is `io.github.elyx0.reactnativedocumentpicker` supposed to come from? Have you included the necessary dependencies in your build?